# Delete all rows with meaning 'Yellow' in col1 if during 24 hours follows something not null in the col2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wish to delete all the rows with meaning 'Yellow' in col1 if during 24 hours follows something not null in the col2 or something not null and not 'Yellow' in the col1 (inside the same client)

The dataset is:

```
client    datetime              col1    col2
-----------------------------------------------
1     2019-05-20 14:30:08.000   NULL    Green
1     2019-05-31 12:23:55.000   Yellow  NULL
1     2019-05-31 13:00:08.000   NULL    Green
2     2019-09-10 12:22:17.000   Yellow  NULL
2     2019-09-10 13:30:57.000   NULL    Green
3     2019-09-14 07:34:41.000   Red     NULL
3     2019-09-13 07:45:24.000   Yellow  NULL
4     2019-01-15 14:15:08.000   Yellow  NULL
4     2019-01-15 14:48:40.000   NULL    Green
5     2019-06-24 16:13:29.000   NULL    Green
5     2019-06-25 13:14:07.000   Yellow  NULL
6     2019-09-06 11:22:19.000   Yellow  NULL
6     2019-09-06 12:19:48.000   NULL    Green
6     2019-10-08 12:19:08.000   Red     NULL
```

If there is some value in the col1, col2 = null and backwards.

Rows that should be deleted:

```
client    datetime              col1    col2
---------------------------------------------
1     2019-05-31 12:23:55.000   Yellow  NULL
2     2019-09-10 12:22:17.000   Yellow  NULL
3     2019-09-13 07:45:24.000   Yellow  NULL
4     2019-01-15 14:15:08.000   Yellow  NULL
6     2019-09-06 11:22:19.000   Yellow  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a simple `exists`:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T As Table (
    [client] int, 
    [datetime] datetime, 
    [col1] varchar(6), 
    [col2] varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO @T ([client], [datetime], [col1], [col2]) VALUES
(1, '2019-05-20T14:30:08', NULL, 'Green'),
(1, '2019-05-31T12:23:55', 'Yellow', NULL),
(1, '2019-05-31T13:00:08', NULL, 'Green'),
(2, '2019-09-10T12:22:17', 'Yellow', NULL),
(2, '2019-09-10T13:30:57', NULL, 'Green'),
(3, '2019-09-14T07:34:41', 'Red', NULL),
(3, '2019-09-13T07:45:24', 'Yellow', NULL),
(4, '2019-01-15T14:15:08', 'Yellow', NULL),
(4, '2019-01-15T14:48:40', NULL, 'Green'),
(5, '2019-06-24T16:13:29', NULL, 'Green'),
(5, '2019-06-25T13:14:07', 'Yellow', NULL),
(6, '2019-09-06T11:22:19', 'Yellow', NULL),
(6, '2019-09-06T12:19:48', NULL, 'Green'),
(6, '2019-10-08T12:19:08', 'Red', NULL);
```

Then, the delete statement:

```
DELETE t1
FROM @T AS t1
WHERE t1.col1 = 'Yellow'
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @T t2
    WHERE t2.[datetime] > t1.[datetime]
    AND t2.[datetime] <= DATEADD(HOUR, 24, t1.[datetime])
    AND t2.[client] = t1.[client]
    AND (
        t2.[col2] IS NOT NULL
        OR t2.[col1] <> 'Yellow'
    )
)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](https://rextester.com/XBAXO4830)

Comment: Zohar, thank you. Your code works perfect, but why did you use in delete statement 'AND t2.[client] = t2.[client]'? May be - 'AND t1.[client] = t2.[client]' should be used?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed now. Glad to help :-)

Comment: Zohar, if I try to delete the rows, the error occurs: Incorrect syntax near 't1'. I guess, it is because I want to delete from the table where I select from. Is there the way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, add the alias t1 between the `delete` and `from` keywords. I've edited my answer with the corrected code.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)